# mariadb losing primary key on update

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, mariadb

One of my tables is losing the primary key every time I make an update on that particular table.

```
Describe zizi_card_household
```

gives me this result after the update.

```
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    | auto_increment |
| householdnumber   | varchar(45)  | NO   |     |         |                |
| cardnumber        | varchar(45)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| startdate         | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| enddate           | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| assignedby        | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| assigneddate      | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

Where it should normally be

```
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| householdnumber   | varchar(45)  | NO   | MUL |         |                |
| cardnumber        | varchar(45)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| startdate         | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| enddate           | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| assignedby        | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |


SHOW CREATE TABLE
```

will give this statement which shows a primary key was defined. It's possible that entry is updated whenever the table is altered so it shows the table as it was last altered or created.

```
CREATE TABLE `zizi_card_household` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `householdnumber` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `cardnumber` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `startdate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `enddate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `assignedby` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `assigneddate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `deassignedby` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
.
.
.
.
 `modifiedby` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reprintstatus` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `printeddate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `printedby` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_householdnumber` (`householdnumber`),
  KEY `idx_cardnumber` (`cardnumber`),
  KEY `idx_deassignedby` (`deassignedby`),
.
.
.
.
 KEY `idx_reprintstatus` (`reprintstatus`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=860137 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Attempting to add a primary key

```
ALTER TABLE `labour`.`zizi_card_household` 
CHANGE COLUMN `id` `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

at this point gives me

```
ERROR 1068 (42000): Multiple primary key defined
```

Repair table

```
repair table zizi_card_household;
```

Gives me this but it does solve the problem. The primary key returns but will get ruined the next time the table is updated.

```
+----------------------------+--------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Table                      | Op     | Msg_type | Msg_text                                                |
+----------------------------+--------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| labour.zizi_card_household | repair | note     | The storage engine for the table doesn't support repair |
+----------------------------+--------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

The table and other tables have a trigger that updates a summary table. It deletes related rows and reconstructs them. It does something like

```
 FOR EACH ROW

begin
delete from zizi_card_summary where householdnumber=new.householdnumber;
insert into zizi_card_summary(
    cardnumber,cardhouseholdid,householdnumber,startdate,enddate,assignedby
.
.
.
)
select ch.cardnumber,ch.id,b.householdnumber,
    ch.startdate,ch.enddate,ch.assignedby,
.
.
.
.
where b.householdnumber=new.householdnumber and b.beneficiary_type=0;
end
```

All other tables work just fine. Thanks. Been playing around with this for a week. The application is a Zend framework 1.12.

The db version is 10.1.11-MariaDB-log. The operating system is Linux 2.6.32-573.8.1.el6.x86_64 x86_64.

Comment: Does `SHOW CREATE TABLE` always show the `PRIMARY KEY`?  If so, then perhaps the problem is really that `DESCRIBE` is broken, not that the PK is gone.

Comment: To test, `SELECT 1 FROM zizi_card_household WHERE id = 754321;` and see how fast it comes back.  With the PK, it will be 'instantaneous'; without it, it will have to read the entire table and be slow.

Comment: Either way, please file a bug on mariadb.com .

Comment: @rick-james `SHOW CREATE TABLE` always shows the primary key. so does `SHOW INDEX`. using the test you just gave me, the result is always instantaneous. so `DESCRIBE` is probably broken. S I will post a bug on mariadb.com

Comment: I went around this by removing `BEFORE INSERT` and `BEFORE UPDATE` triggers on the table. All the SQL statements in these triggers were commented and they were not doing anything so I can't explain why they were a problem. Also, after the problem was solved, an old problem where the database keeps throwing 'Lock wait timeout' errors came back and they are probably part of the problem. I will eventually remove triggers completely.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm the bug and the workaround as described by Timothy : removing the trigger keeps the Primary key after a record update. 
Bug resolution progress is on https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-9558